# Program Crashes when calculate button is clicked

Tags: android, button, crash, crash-reports

> > I have an application that crashes when the calculate button is clicked. In the program, a user enters the food information from a drop down menu list and then enters their information along with the order. The order total is then calculated with text and the toast message displays with their order information in the second activity (Food_Total).

```
        >>Here are print screens of the code:

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static String priceString= "";

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

          @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Food_Total.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");//decimal format for dollars
                    EditText mealNameBox= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    String mealNameString= mealNameBox.getText().toString();
                    EditText mealPriceBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    String priceString = mealPriceBox.getText().toString();
                    Double priceDouble= Double.parseDouble(priceString);

                    //Sales tax for VA
                    String tax= "4%";

                    String percentString= tax.toString();
                    //Calculate taxes for food
                    double taxfood= priceDouble * .04;

                    String taxfood_string= Double.toString(taxfood);


                    //Calculate food total
                    double food_total= taxfood + priceDouble;

                    String food_total_string= Double.toString(food_total);

                    b.putString("Meal Price:", "" + df.format(priceString));
                    b.putString("Tax: ", tax);
                    b.putString("Food Total: ", "" + df.format(food_total));

                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    //Toast.makeText(this, "" + tip, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }


    Food_Total Activity (displays toast message):

        public class Food_Total extends Activity {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_food__total);
                //get info from intent
                Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

                // #####################################################
                //Updated key values on bundle so that they
                // match the MainActivity class
                // #####################################################
                String meal_nameString= b.getString("MealName");
                String mealString = b.getString("MealPrice");
                String percentString = b.getString("TaxRate");
                String tax_foodString= b.getString("TaxAmount");
                String food_totalString= b.getString("Total");

                //results output info
                String results = meal_nameString + getString(R.string.mealNameString) +
                "\n" + mealString + getString(R.string.mealPrice)+ ": $"+ 
                "\n" + percentString + "%" +  
                "\n" + tax_foodString + getString(R.string.taxfood_string) + ": $"  +
                "\n" + food_totalString + getString(R.string.food_total_string);

                //create text view
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setTextSize(30);
                textView.setText(results);

                //set view as the activity layout
                setContentView(textView);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_food__total, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case android.R.id.home:
                        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                        return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        Layout XML:

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:text="Student Name: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Food_Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_lbl"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name_lbl"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:text="Food Name:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Food_Name"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Food_Name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Food_Name"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:text="Food Price: "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name_lbl"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="44dp" >

            </ListView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/calculate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:text="Calculate" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    >>Android Manifest File:

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.food_activity_final"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".Food_Total"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_food__total" >

                     <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>

    >>Thank you for your help! Let me know if you need to know anything more about the program.
```

Comment: Check the logs what's causing the crash. If you can't decipher it, please paste it here.

Comment: This isn't your problem but you call toString() on a string which probably isn't necessary, unless I missed something

Comment: The only error I get in the console is this: [2012-10-29 17:04:12 - com.example.food_activity_final.MainActivity] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: Go into device settings and manually force close the application and try again. It sounds like the program is being closed completely

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I can close the application with the X button on the top of the virtual machine.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I'm used to testing on a device. Do that so that the application isn't in memory and run it. You have to get some sort of error if it is crashing. If you don't get an error then you will have to define "crashing". What environment are you developing in? Eclipse?

Comment: Where are you inflating your button and setting it's listener in your MainActivity?

Comment: @EvanWiley can you please upload your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

How are these Activities defined in AndroidManifest.xml? MainActivity should have an intent filter as follows:
            
                
                
            
The other Activity also has to be in there, but it should *not* have an intent filter.

Comment: I got rid of the intent filter for food total and it still hasn't done anything.

Comment: I'll upload the Android Manifest file.